Calculating same statistic for several layers
I have several layer groups:

Each of my groups consists of layers which have the same names representing different bands:

My goal is to use the raster calculator on each of these groups to calculate statistics (in this case NDVI, but it could be anything). When I use the raster calculator (Raster > Raster Calculator), groups are not conserved within the "Raster Bands" and they are assigned random numbers not associated with the groups. When you mouse over one of the bands you can see which file it came from. Notice in the following pictures that "results@1" and "results_Green@1" are not files from the same group:



What I am curious about is that if there is a good way to do this. I want to calculate the exact same statistics for each of my layer groups. In reality I have many more groups. My current method is to just rename all the files within a group and then manually enter ractor calculations for each. This is very time consuming to do when I have many groups.
Is there a better way to replicate the raster calculations?
